# Tried to copy a working existing java class into a servlet, com.mysql.jdbc.Driver error

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc

first of all, I builded the path(in eclipse). The java class is working fine when I run it as a java application, and I got the access to the server where the data are. 
But when I want to run it on a server, it is always throwing "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

That's the my first problem,
annother occures when I copy the fine working java app (without the class, just the code below) into the servlet and just want to see the output I get when I run the java class as an app.

I'm new at java and I have to do this for the university(which gave me a working "Testklasse" as testclass to test if the database connection is working, the whole CMS package was written by them.)

please help.

Java Class:

```
package myCMS;



/**
 * Testprogramm fÃ¼r das myCMS-Model.
 * Wird nicht benÃ¶tigt, sondern dient lediglich zum Ausprobieren, ob die Verbindung zur Datenbank funktioniert.
 */
public class Testklasse {

    /**
     * Einstiegsmethode fÃ¼r das Testprogramm
     * @param args Array der Kommandozeilenparameter
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Model-Objekt erstellen
        WebUserAgentModel repModel = new WebUserAgentModel();

        System.out.println("*** Testprogramm ***\n");

        System.out.println("Es wurden die folgenden Nachrichtenkategorien gefunden:");

        // Alle Nachrichten-Kategorien abrufen (z.B. fÃ¼r die Navigationsleiste)
        List<RepositoryCategory> catList = repModel.getCategoryList();

        // Alle Elemente der Kategorien-Liste ausgeben
        for (RepositoryCategory category : catList) {   // entspricht "foreach"
            System.out.println ("[" + category.getId() + "]  " + category.getTitel());
        }

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Die folgenden Artikel befinden sich in der Datenbank:");

        // Alle Nachrichtenmeldungen/Dokumente abrufen (aus allen Kategorien)
        repModel.selectDocuments();
        //repModel.selectDocumentsByQuery("HERSTELLER");  

        // Dokumentenliste abrufen
        List<RepositoryDocument> docList = repModel.getDocumentList();

        // Alle Meldungen auszugsweise ausgeben
        int count = 0;
        for (RepositoryDocument article : docList) {
            System.out.printf( "[%2d]  %-10.10s  %-12.12s  %-60.60s%n", article.getId(), article.getDatum(), article.getUntertitel(), article.getText() );
            count++;
        }

        // ZÃ¤hlergebnis ausgeben
        System.out.println("\n" + count + " EintrÃ¤ge gefunden.\n\n");


        // RubrikÃ¼bersicht:   (NEU)
        System.out.println("Ãœbersicht Ã¼ber die Artikel in den Rubriken:");
        for (RepositoryCategory category : catList) {
            System.out.println("\n++ " + category.getTitel() + " ++");
            repModel.selectTeaser(category.getId());
            docList = repModel.getTeaserList();
            for (RepositoryDocument teaser : docList) {
                System.out.printf( "[%2d]  %-10.10s  ", teaser.getId(), teaser.getDatum());
                System.out.println(teaser.getText());
            }
        }


        // Datenbankverbindung schlieÃŸen
        repModel.closeDatabase();

    }

}
```

Servlet:

```
package myCMS;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class MobileNewsServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/MobileNewsServlet")
public class MobileNewsServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public MobileNewsServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html");

         WebUserAgentModel repModel = new WebUserAgentModel();

            System.out.println("*** Testprogramm ***\n");

            System.out.println("Es wurden die folgenden Nachrichtenkategorien gefunden:");

            // Alle Nachrichten-Kategorien abrufen (z.B. fÃ¼r die Navigationsleiste)
            List<RepositoryCategory> catList = repModel.getCategoryList();

            // Alle Elemente der Kategorien-Liste ausgeben
            for (RepositoryCategory category : catList) {   // entspricht "foreach"
                System.out.println ("[" + category.getId() + "]  " + category.getTitel());
            }

            System.out.println("");

            System.out.println("Die folgenden Artikel befinden sich in der Datenbank:");

            // Alle Nachrichtenmeldungen/Dokumente abrufen (aus allen Kategorien)
            repModel.selectDocuments();
            //repModel.selectDocumentsByQuery("HERSTELLER");  

            // Dokumentenliste abrufen
            List<RepositoryDocument> docList = repModel.getDocumentList();

            // Alle Meldungen auszugsweise ausgeben
            int count = 0;
            for (RepositoryDocument article : docList) {
                System.out.printf( "[%2d]  %-10.10s  %-12.12s  %-60.60s%n", article.getId(), article.getDatum(), article.getUntertitel(), article.getText() );
                count++;
            }

            // ZÃ¤hlergebnis ausgeben
            System.out.println("\n" + count + " EintrÃ¤ge gefunden.\n\n");


            // RubrikÃ¼bersicht:   (NEU)
            System.out.println("Ãœbersicht Ã¼ber die Artikel in den Rubriken:");
            for (RepositoryCategory category : catList) {
                System.out.println("\n++ " + category.getTitel() + " ++");
                repModel.selectTeaser(category.getId());
                docList = repModel.getTeaserList();
                for (RepositoryDocument teaser : docList) {
                    System.out.printf( "[%2d]  %-10.10s  ", teaser.getId(), teaser.getDatum());
                    System.out.println(teaser.getText());
                }
            }


            // Datenbankverbindung schlieÃŸen
            repModel.closeDatabase();

            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/mobilenews.jsp");
                    rd.forward(request,response);



    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you placed mysql.jar in lib folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Put **mysql-connector-java-version-bin** jar in **WEB-INF/lib** folder
```